# Kentico 9 REST - Access Denied for FAQs

Tags: rest, kentico

I'm trying to retrieve data from Kentico 9 using the REST api. I can retrieve country data without any issues using the following URL:

http://localhost/EPS/rest/cms.country

However, I want to be able to retrieve data for FAQs. When I use the following URL I get a 403 Access Denied:

http://localhost/EPS/rest/CMS.Faq

I've tried using HASH parameter authentication but that made no difference. There are no restrictions set on the REST service.

Any ideas what might be going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came across same issue when I was trying to get object data from CMS.Office.
I think what we you are missing is specifying the correct object type.

Please have a look at following url to specify your object type.

http://devnet.kentico.com/articles/tips-and-tricks-listing-object-types